# getting unique value from object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of Objects which is look like this

```
object=
[
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`fish`,
  type:`marine`,
 }
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`fish`,
  type:`fresh`,
 }
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`fish`,
  type:`tank`,
 }
 {
  id:`04`,
  name:`animal`,
  type:`pet`,
 }
 {
  id:`05`,
  name:`animal`,
  type:`wild`,
 }
 {
  id:`06`,
  name:`animal`,
  type:`zoo`,
 }
 {
  id:`07`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`veg`,
 }
 {
  id:`08`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`non-veg`,
 }
]
```

I want to store them uniquely but in string format so when i call them i can fetch them easily

- I tried to get value by using map function

```js
let object=
    [
     {
      id:`01`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`marine`,
     },
     {
      id:`02`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`fresh`,
     },
     {
      id:`03`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`tank`,
     },
     {
      id:`04`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`pet`,
     },
     {
      id:`05`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`wild`,
     },
     {
      id:`06`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`zoo`,
     },
     {
      id:`07`,
      name:`food`,
      type:`veg`,
     },
     {
      id:`08`,
      name:`food`,
      type:`non-veg`,
     }
    ]
    
    object.map((value)=>{
console.log(value.name)
})
```

so i am getting the output as

```
fish
fish
fish
animal
animal
animal
food
food
```

- but i need them distinctly

```
fish
animal
food
```

even i tried to store them in one variable to get the output in

```js
let object=
[
 {
  id:`01`,
  name:`fish`,
  type:`marine`,
 },
 {
  id:`02`,
  name:`fish`,
  type:`fresh`,
 },
 {
  id:`03`,
  name:`fish`,
  type:`tank`,
 },
 {
  id:`04`,
  name:`animal`,
  type:`pet`,
 },
 {
  id:`05`,
  name:`animal`,
  type:`wild`,
 },
 {
  id:`06`,
  name:`animal`,
  type:`zoo`,
 },
 {
  id:`07`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`veg`,
 },
 {
  id:`08`,
  name:`food`,
  type:`non-veg`,
 }
]


let gotValue= [...new Set( object.map((value)=>{
return value.name;
}))];

console.log(gotValue);
```

so i am getting this value as

```
[
"fish"
"animal"
"food"
]
```

but i need value in string format

```
expected value=
fish
animal
food
```

Comment: you can use reduce function after map

Comment: btw, why do you use backticks for strings? it is an overhead by using the expression as template string.

Comment: Use the code in your last snippet that uses .map and the set, and then use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with a `\n` or some other delimiter to get a string output

Comment: ```"expected value=\n" + gotValue.join('\n')``` should do the trick.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const object =
[
 {
  id:"01",
  name:"fish",
  type:"marine"
 },
 {
  id:"02",
  name:"fish",
  type:"fresh"
 },
 {
  id:"03",
  name:"fish",
  type:"tank"
 },
 {
  id:"04",
  name:"animal",
  type:"pet"
 },
 {
  id:"05",
  name:"animal",
  type:"wild"
 },
 {
  id:"06",
  name:"animal",
  type:"zoo"
 },
 {
  id:"07",
  name:"food",
  type:"veg"
 },
 {
  id:"08",
  name:"food",
  type:"non-veg"
 }
];

const distinctItems = [...new Map(object.map(item => [item["name"], item.name])).values()];
console.log(distinctItems.join(' '));
```

What you missed was `.join(' ')`
This will work for you.

```
const distinctItems = [...new Map(object.map(item => [item["name"], item.name])).values()];
```

Comment: you miss ```expected value=```, see my comments

Answer (score -1):

Just use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const result = ["expected value=", ...new Set(object.map((o) => o.name))].join("\n");
console.log(result);
```

```js
object = [{
    id: `01`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `marine`,
  },
  {
    id: `02`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `fresh`,
  },
  {
    id: `03`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `tank`,
  },
  {
    id: `04`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: `pet`,
  },
  {
    id: `05`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: `wild`,
  },
  {
    id: `06`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: `zoo`,
  },
  {
    id: `07`,
    name: `food`,
    type: `veg`,
  },
  {
    id: `08`,
    name: `food`,
    type: `non-veg`,
  },
];

const result = ["expected value=", ...new Set(object.map((o) => o.name))].join("\n");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you miss ```expected value= ```, see my comments

Comment: @ikhvjs edited and corrected...